# Выдает ошибку Destination array was not long enough при изменении размера массива

Tags: c#

Выдает ошибку `Destination array was not long enough` при изменении размера массива.

```
void ResizeArray<T>(ref T[,] original, int newCoNum, int newRoNum)
{
    var newArray = new T[newCoNum, newRoNum];
    int columnCount = original.GetLength(1);
    int columnCount2 = newRoNum;
    int columns = original.GetUpperBound(0);
    for (int co = 0; co <= columns; co++)
        Array.Copy(original, co * columnCount, newArray, co * columnCount2, columnCount);
    original = newArray;
}
```

У меня есть таблица, в которой изменяется количество столбцов и строк. Но если таблицу уменьшить, то тогда программа выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас одномерный массив, можно воспользоваться `Array.Resize`. Если двумерный, попробуйте повторить логику из ответов по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539571/how-to-resize-multidimensional-2d-array-in-c

```
T[,] ResizeArray<T>(T[,] original, int rows, int cols)
{
    var newArray = new T[rows,cols];
    int minRows = Math.Min(rows, original.GetLength(0));
    int minCols = Math.Min(cols, original.GetLength(1));
    for(int i = 0; i < minRows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < minCols; j++)
           newArray[i, j] = original[i, j];
    return newArray;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var array = new int[5, 7];
array[1, 2] = 50;
var newArray = ResizeArray(array, 7, 8);
```

Касаемо `Array.Resize`:

```
var array = new int[10];
var newArray = array1;
Array.Resize(ref newArray, 20);
```

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j < minCols; j++) newArray[i, j] = original[i, j];` можно заменить на `Array.Copy(original, i * original.GetLength(1), newArray, i * newArray.GetLength(1), minCols);`, у автора этот момент был правильно сделан.